# Where to put my functions so that it can be called from my switch statement?

Tags: c#

I am very new in C# programming and I have a problem. I dont know where to put my functions and how to declare them so that I can call them from my switch statement. And will I be able to use my numberarr and wordarr array in my functions or do I also need to create a separate function for it Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    enum Menu
    {
        Numbers = 1,
        Words = 2,
        Exit = 3,
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isValid;
        do
        {
            isValid = true;
            Menu menu = 0;
            int number;
            string word;

            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option from the menu: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Numbers ");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Words ");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Exit ");

            switch (menu)
            {
                case Menu.Numbers:

                    List<int> numberarr = new List<int>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like or type exit");
                    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    numberarr.Add(number);



                    break;
                case Menu.Words:
                    List<string> wordarr = new List<string>();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like");
                    word = Console.ReadLine();
                    wordarr.Add(word);

                    break;

                case Menu.Exit:

                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have made an invalid selection, try again");
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (isValid);

    }
}
class Choice
{
    static void Numbers(int sum, int count, int average, int max, int min)
    {

    }

    static void Words(string[] args)
    {

    }
    static void Exit()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You've done nothing to put a value of anything except `0` in `menu`, so your `switch` will never match anything. You do nothing to create an instance of your `Choice` class anywhere, and `Numbers` and `Words` are methods of that class. There are entirely too many problems here for your question to be answered, I'm afraid. You need to look at what your code is doing, and what it's *supposed* to be doing, and try to make those two things match. :-)

Comment: You can cheat and let VS to put functions in correct place - select code you want to be in a function and chose "Extract function" from right click menu (I believe it is available in all editions of VS)...

Comment: Marietjie, would you clarify in case 1 is the person supposed to enter lots of numbers at the console?  Or just one number for each loop iteration?

Comment: @KenWhite the methods in Choice are static so she doesn't need to create an instance of it, she just needs to declare them as public. The switch's control variable is a different issue.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Yep, you're right. I missed the `static`. Doesn't change the fact that you have to reference the class in order to call its methods, though, or that in order to do a `switch` on `menu` you have to first do something  to assign a value to it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the methods defined in the `Choice` class in Main because you haven't declared them with the `public` identifier. In C# class properties default to being `private` so unless you explicitly declare them as `public` only the class itself will know of their existence.

So basically just change all of declarations in `Choice` from `static void MethodName` to `public static void MethodName` and then you will be able to call them in main from the `Choice` class like;

```
   Choice.Exit();
```

EDIT: You'll also need to make some changes to make the switch statement work. As pointed out in the comments there is no way for `menu` to have a value other than 0. I suggest you use something more like the following;

```
        isValid = true;
        int menu = 0;
        int number;
        string word;

        Console.WriteLine("What type do you want to use?");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for numbers, 2 for words, or 3 exit.");
        string input = Console.ReadLine(); // we must read the users input

        if (!int.TryParse(input, out menu))
        {
             // the user didn't enter a number make them try again
             // note you might want to use a loop here to ensure the program does not
             // proceed until the user has entered "1", "2", or "3"
        }

        switch (menu)
```

Comment: @MarietjieDavel, you can press the 'accept' button to acknowledge Evan's answer as helpful for you

Comment: @MarietjieDavel you are very welcome. Good luck with the homework.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, just place your functions within your class. I've adjusted your code accordingly. You may also have problems with your word/num classes. You normally have to instantiate them but with something like Choice myChoice = new Choice();
Class Program
{
    enum Menu
    {
        Numbers = 1,
        Words = 2,
        Exit = 3,
    }

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isValid;
    do
    {
        isValid = true;
        Menu menu = 0;
        int number;
        string word;

        Console.WriteLine("Choose an option from the menu: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Numbers ");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Words ");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Exit ");

        switch (menu)
        {
            case Menu.Numbers:

                List<int> numberarr = new List<int>();
                Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like or type exit");
                number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                numberarr.Add(number);
                int retInt = functionGetInt(number) 


                break;
            case Menu.Words:
                List<string> wordarr = new List<string>();
                Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like");
                word = Console.ReadLine();
                wordarr.Add(word);
                string retString = functionGetString(word);
                break;

            case Menu.Exit:

                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You have made an invalid selection, try again");
                isValid = false;
                break;
        }
    } while (isValid);
private string functionGetString(string pParmString)
{
//code
return "string";
}
private int functionGetInt(int pParmInt)
{

//code
return 0;
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

For the code you presented here this would be one possibility.I removed the enum,i normally try to deal with the code presented but yes it was not necessary:

```
    class Program
    {
        //enum Menu
        //{
        //    Numbers = 1,
        //    Words = 2,
        //    Exit = 3,
        //}

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isValid;
            do
            {
                isValid = true;
                int menu = 0;
                int[] number;
                string word;

                Console.WriteLine("Choose an option from the menu: ");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Numbers ");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Words ");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Exit ");

                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                while (!Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[1-3]{1}$"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid choice(1 to 3)");
                    s = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                menu = Convert.ToInt32(s);
                switch (menu)
                {
                    case 1:
                        List<int> numberarr = new List<int>();
                        Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like separeted by space or comma,or type exit");
                        string numbers = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (numbers == "exit")
                            Choice.Exit();
                        else
                        {
                            number = numbers.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
                            numberarr.AddRange(number);
                            Choice.Numbers(numberarr.Sum(), numberarr.Count, numberarr.Average(), numberarr.Max(), numberarr.Min());
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        List<string> wordarr = new List<string>();
                        Console.WriteLine("Please input as many numbers as you like separeted by space or comma");
                        word = Console.ReadLine();
                        wordarr.AddRange(word.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }));
                        Choice.Words(wordarr);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Choice.Exit();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You have made an invalid selection, try again");
                        isValid = false;
                        break;
                }
            } while (isValid);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Choice
    {
        public static void Numbers(int sum, int count, double average, int max, int min)
        {
            int a = sum;
            int b = count;
            double c = average;
            int d = max;
            int e = min;
            //just as example.
        }

        public static void Words(List<string> args)
        {
            //do whatever you need here
        }
        public static void Exit()
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a start in the right direction however it will throw exceptions. You will get an invalid cast exception if the result of `Convert.Int32` is not 1, 2, or 3 and `Convert.Int32` will throw an exception if the input is not an integer.

Comment: The edits you made don't address that problem. For her purposes this is likely sufficient however, this would not be acceptable in enterprise software or really any customer facing software. Input validation is required.

Comment: I am looking to call a function, scroll down you will see what I am talking about....

Comment: Take a string from the console...  Then parse it into an int...  and implicitly cast it to an enum...  So that you can switch on it?  Don't we have an Enum.TryParse?  The enum is superfluous anyway.  Just switch on the string!